# How do I include box parameters at the point of use?

Tags: formatting

I have created many of the following customized boxes, but I'm sure there's a better way of achieving the same result: I would like to use something that calls the parameters at the point of use like:

```
\myuniversalbox[background_color=, frame_color=, borderlinewidth=, arc_radius=, separation_x=, separation_y=]{some text}.
```

The method of how to define the colors, etc, is not an issue; the issue is how to set the whole thing up within the .tex file.

```
%------------------------- %
\documentclass{book}
%------------------------- %
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx} %
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
%
\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.00}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{rgb}{0.96,0.96,0.96}
\definecolor{LightPink}{rgb}{1.00,0.92,0.92}
\definecolor{LightYellow}{rgb}{1.00,1.00,0.85} 
\definecolor{PaleBlue}{rgb}{0.92,1.00,1.00} 

\newcommand{\redpaleblueboxtwofour}[1]{ %
 \setlength{\fboxrule}{1.25pt}
  {\setlength{\fboxsep}{2.4pt}
    \hspace{-4pt}\fcolorbox{DarkRed}{PaleBlue}{#1}}}

\newcommand{\redlightyellowboxsixeight}[1]{ %
 \setlength{\fboxrule}{1.25pt}
  {\setlength{\fboxsep}{6.8pt}
    \hspace{-4pt}\fcolorbox{DarkRed}{LightYellow}{#1}}}

\newcommand{\redlightpinkthreesix}[1]{ %
 \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt}
  {\setlength{\fboxsep}{3.6pt}
    \hspace{-4pt}\fcolorbox{DarkRed}{LightPink}{#1}}}

\newcommand{\redlightgreyboxfoureight}[1]{ %
 \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt}
  {\setlength{\fboxsep}{4.8pt}
    \hspace{-4pt}\fcolorbox{DarkRed}{LightGrey}{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace{50pt}\fbox{Some ordinary text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \hspace{50pt}\redpaleblueboxtwofour{Some ordinary text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \hspace{50pt}\redlightyellowboxsixeight{Some ordinary text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \hspace{50pt}\redlightpinkthreesix{Some ordinary text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \hspace{50pt}\redlightgreyboxfoureight{Some ordinary text $+\hspace{1.2pt}x^{\hspace{0.6pt}2}$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two other ways to do this:

One way is to use one of the packages for key-value options. In the code below `pgfkeys` was used. This doesn't get you rounded corners or different distances on the left and right of the text, as your example suggests.

So the other way is to use the `tcolorbox` package, which can do everything you want and much more. The example in the code below barely scratches the surface of its capabilities.

```
%------------------------- %
\documentclass{book}
%------------------------- %
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
%\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx} %
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
%

\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.00}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{rgb}{0.96,0.96,0.96}
\definecolor{LightPink}{rgb}{1.00,0.92,0.92}
\definecolor{LightYellow}{rgb}{1.00,1.00,0.85} 
\definecolor{PaleBlue}{rgb}{0.92,1.00,1.00} 

% define the options
\pgfkeys{%
  /mybox/.is family, /mybox/.cd,
  background color/.code={\colorlet{bgcolor}{#1}},
  frame color/.code={\colorlet{framecolor}{#1}},
  frame sep/.code={\setlength{\fboxsep}{#1}},
  frame width/.code={\setlength{\fboxrule}{#1}},
  % initialize colors
  background color=white,
  frame color=black
}

% universal box
\newcommand{\mybox}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{mybox,#1}%
  \fcolorbox{framecolor}{bgcolor}{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\redpaleblueboxtwofour}[1]{%
 \mybox[frame width=1.25pt,
        frame sep=2.4pt,
        frame color=DarkRed,
        background color=PaleBlue]{#1}}

\newcommand{\redlightyellowboxsixeight}[1]{%
 \mybox[frame width=1.25pt,
        frame sep=6.8pt,
        frame color=DarkRed,
        background color=LightYellow]{#1}}

\newcommand{\redlightpinkthreesix}[1]{%
 \mybox[frame width=0.75pt,
        frame sep=3.6pt,
        frame color=DarkRed,
        background color=LightPink]{#1}}

\newcommand{\redlightgreyboxfoureight}[1]{%
 \mybox[frame width=0.75pt,
        frame sep=4.8pt,
        frame color=DarkRed,
        background color=LightGrey]{#1}}


\begin{document}

\noindent \fbox{Some ordinary text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \redpaleblueboxtwofour{Some ordinary text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \redlightyellowboxsixeight{Some ordinary text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \redlightpinkthreesix{Some ordinary text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \redlightgreyboxfoureight{Some ordinary text $+\hspace{1.2pt}x^{\hspace{0.6pt}2}$}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \mybox{Some Text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \mybox[frame width=5pt,frame sep=10pt,frame color=blue,background color=cyan]{Some Text}


\vspace{20pt}
\noindent With \texttt{tcolorbox} and global settings\\
\texttt{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,colframe=DarkRed,colback=PaleBlue}

\tcbset{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,colframe=DarkRed,colback=PaleBlue}% set some things globally

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \tcbox{Some other Text}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \tcbox[arc=2mm]{Some other Text} \texttt{arc=2mm}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \tcbox[sharp corners]{Some other Text} \texttt{sharp corners}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \tcbox[boxsep=2mm]{Some other Text} \texttt{boxsep=2mm}

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent \tcbox[boxrule=2mm]{Some other Text} \texttt{boxrule=2mm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My goodness, I'm so grateful to you all for such comprehensive answers.  If you will bear with me, I will trial all the options before accepting a best answer.

Comment: Mike.  In the tcolorbox part of your answer, what values are assigned to nobeforeafter and tcbox raise base?  I've tried false and 6pt respectively, with no effect.  I'm particularly interested in controlling "separation_x" and "separation_y" - if they exist; otherwise, I think tcolorbox is exactly what I need.

Comment: @keith77777 a `\tcbox` is normaly printed as its own paragraph. `nobeforeafter` makes it an inline box. Try `before \tcbox{some text} after` with and without this option. `tcbox raise base` raises the box so the base lines of text inside and outside the box are on the same height. Again, try it with and without. The option `on line` combines both options (just learned this). And for the seperation, you are probably looking for `left` and `right`. On page 11 of the `tcolorbox` manual you can find an overview of those options. They are links to their descriptions.

Comment: I accept your second answer (tcbox) as the best; the syntax associated with your first answer is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @keith77777 `tcolorbox` also uses `pgfkeys` for its parameters. This enables you to write e.g. `\tcbset{myinlinebox/.style={on line, colframe=blue, colback=LightYellow, arc=2mm}}`, which defines a new parameter `myinlinebox`, which sets the parameters given in `={...}`. Then you can just write `\tcbox[myinlinebox]{Some Text}` instead of always giving all the parameters above. The same scheme is used by `TikZ`, `pgfplots` and other packages. So I think it's worth the effort to familiarize yourself with `pgfkeys`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a LaTeX3 solution that processes the various parameters for the box and then puts them into place so that

```
  \UniversalBox{With defaults}
  \UniversalBox[background color=LightYellow]{Yellow background}
  \UniversalBox[background color=PaleBlue, borderline width=2pt, 
                frame color=DarkRed]{More text}
  \UniversalBox{More text}
```

produces

[image]

Here is the full code

```
%------------------------- %
\documentclass{book}
%------------------------- %
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} %
\usepackage{xparse}
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.00}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{rgb}{0.96,0.96,0.96}
\definecolor{LightPink}{rgb}{1.00,0.92,0.92}
\definecolor{LightYellow}{rgb}{1.00,1.00,0.85}
\definecolor{PaleBlue}{rgb}{0.92,1.00,1.00}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {universalbox}
{
  arc radius       .dim_set:N = \l_univbox_arc_radius_dim,
  background color .tl_set:N  = \l_univbox_background_color_tl,
  borderline width .dim_set:N = \l_univbox_borderlinewidth_dim,
  frame color      .tl_set:N  = \l_univbox_frame_color_tl,
  separation x     .dim_set:N = \l_univbox_separation_x_dim,
  separation y     .dim_set:N = \l_univbox_separation_y_dim,
  arc radius       .initial:n = 1pt, % default values 
  background color .initial:n = White,
  borderline width .initial:n = 0.5pt,
  frame color      .initial:n = Black,
  separation x     .initial:n = 2pt,
  separation y     .initial:n = 2pt
}
% \UniversalBox[optional box settings]{text}
\NewDocumentCommand\UniversalBox{ O{} m }{
  % start a group to keep key setting local
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn{universalbox}{#1}
    \setlength {\fboxrule} {\l_univbox_borderlinewidth_dim}
    \setlength {\fboxsep} {\l_univbox_separation_x_dim}
    \hspace {\l_univbox_separation_y_dim}
    \fcolorbox{\l_univbox_frame_color_tl}{\l_univbox_background_color_tl}{#2}
  \group_end:% close group
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \UniversalBox{With defaults}
  \UniversalBox[background color=LightYellow]{Yellow background}
  \UniversalBox[background color=PaleBlue, borderline width=2pt, 
                frame color=DarkRed]{More text}
  \UniversalBox{More text}

\end{document}
```

Apologies to those who know how to use expl3. Please feel free to correct!

Comment: `\setlength{\fboxrule}{\l_univbox_borderlinewidth_dim}` is the correct syntax: a `dim` variable is not expandable. Also the argument should be `O{}` rather than `o`: `\keys_set:nn{...}{#1}` does nothing if the argument is empty.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the corrections and improvements!